# Marketing Cloud's trial user

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have already created a Trial User on Salesforce but I can not access into Marketing Cloud.
How can I have a Trial User on Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Have you enabled "Market user" checkbox in user level

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are no trial or developer accounts for marketing cloud. They have been used for spam in the past and therefore been discontinued.

If you work for a registered salesforce partner you can order a free partner account. This procedure is detailed in the salesforce partner portal.